# Accessing a Web API from JavaScript after being authenticated against Azure AD B2C

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am developing a .Net Web App where after authenticating against Azure AD B2C through the Azure AD Connect protocol the controller in my app gets an access token through the MSAL library (C# code) to access a backed Web API. That works all fine.
Now from the same web app I need to use JavaScript to access the same backed Web API. My question is how can I leverage the access token obtained through my server side C# code to get my client side JavaScript to access the Web API without being prompted to sign-in.

I used the sample code on GitHub to get me started.
Below is my JavaScript code. When I run it I get the following error `"user_login_error:User` login is required"

```
if (!clientApplication) {
    clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(window.config.clientID, window.config.authority, authCallback);
    clientApplication.redirectUri = window.config.redirectUri;
}

function ReloadInfo(type, language, location) {
    clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(window.config.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
        ReadResource(accessToken, type, language, location);
    }, function (error) {
        clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(window.config.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
            ReadResource(accessToken, type, language, location);
        }, function (error) {
            debugger
            logMessage("Error acquiring the access token to call the Web api:\n" + error);
        });
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your correctly

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this scenario is that you can create a corresponding controller to call the web API.

And in the JavaScript, you can call your web app instead of the web API directly. Since you have sign-in, the JavaScript can call the controller successfully. And in this sencario, there is no need to use MSAL library for JavaScript.

### Update

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Location").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.html",//modify the path HTTP request you wanted
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);// handle the result data here
            });
        });
    })


</script>
```

You can refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/) about full jQuery document.

Comment: Yes I do already have a controller within my web app that calls the Web API. But how do I call this controller code which is running on the web server, from my JavaScript which is running on the browser. Thank you Fei.

Comment: It is normal as you call any other web API. You can call that action of control    via Jquery by providing the URL for the specific action.

Comment: Hmmm I am confused now. I thought you said I can call my Web App controller function directly from my JavaScript and now it seems like you are saying that I need to call my Web API using jQuery? If I do that then don't I have to get first an access token for the Web API? How would the context of my session to Azure AD be preserved across my JavaScript and C# code?

Comment: The Jquery library is not necessary but easy to call you web app controller or you will use the raw JavaScript to handle the HTTP request and response which is complex. When the client side call the web app controller, it using the cookie so you can call the web app controller successfully after users sign-in.  And then the web app controller could using the access token acquire before to call the API you want using C#. Please let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: Thanks Fei for your help. Now I have to find some sample code to see how to call a Controller function from JavaScript. I will let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: Fei, here is my Web App Controller code that does a Web API call to get some resources:

Comment: @Rostam We can add the `change` event for the `select` control we want monitor. And I have updated the post to append a code sample using jQuery.